# Puppet: how to remove a directory and everything in it

Tags: puppet

I'm sure this is really simple, but I cannot work it out.

I want to delete the directory `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1`. My attempts thus far have managed to remove everything inside the directory `1.0.0.1`, but I can't work out how to remove the actual directory.

I did think about going up a level, but that would mean that when I copy across the new version of this module (`2.2.5`), on the next run, Puppet will delete it.

Here are my two attempts:

#### file resource

```
file { "${modules_path}/PowerShellGet/1.0.0.1" :
  ensure  => directory,
  recurse => true,
  purge   => true,
  force   => true,
}
```

#### tidy resource

```
tidy { "${modules_path}/PowerShellGet/1.0.0.1" :
  age     => 0,
  recurse => true,
  rmdirs  => true,
}
```

T.I.A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
file { "${modules_path}/PowerShellGet/1.0.0.1" :
  ensure  => absent,
  recurse => true,
  force   => true,
}
```